# How do i get EC_v1 version of Apple Pay PaymentToken

Tags: ios, swift, payment-processing, applepay

I'm trying to Integrate Apple Pay in my application. Following the online docs and some SO help, I've managed to show the Apple Pay payment dialog and all the call backs are configured.

the response returned from the Apple Pay is something like this

```
{
"version": "RSA_v1",
"signature": "somestring",
"data": "DP...A=",
"header": {
    "wrappedKey": "MF...5g==",
    "publicKeyHash": "kd...l4=",
    "transactionId": "a5...3e"
    }
}
```

But my requirement is to get `ephemeralPublicKey` under `header` object. According to [Apple Pay Payment Token Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014929)
 the returned object is correct as its `RSA_v1 version` which will not have `ephemeralPublicKey` but `wrappedKey`. Now my question is how do i get `EC_v1 version` of the returned token object.

May be I'm missing something here in the docs but please someone point me to the right direction. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get this returned response from the Apple Pay Gateway server. You can't see this response in the console directly. You can see this response only if you will log it on the server by using an ajax request. See mine below sample URL and my source code.

**Full Documentation for beginners**
https://gist.github.com/jagdeepsingh/c538e21f3839f65732a5932e35809d60

```
session.onpaymentauthorized = (event) => {

    $("#paymentMethodVal").val("apple-pay");
    $form = $("#reservation-form");

    console.log($form.serialize());
    callRequest({
        url: '/reserve/init-apple-pay',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            token: event.payment.token,
            reservationData: $form.serialize()
        },
        beforeRequest: function(e) {},
        afterRequest: function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response.status){
               toastr.success(response.message);
               session.completePayment(ApplePaySession.STATUS_SUCCESS);
            }else{
                toastr.error(response.message.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g).join('<br/>'));
                session.completePayment(ApplePaySession.STATUS_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

`token: event.payment.token,` line is your answer this will send data directly to server and you can log data over there.

```
{
 "version": "RSA_v1",
 "signature": "somestring",
 "data": "DP...A=",
 "header": {
   "wrappedKey": "MF...5g==",
   "publicKeyHash": "kd...l4=",
   "transactionId": "a5...3e"
 }
}
```